# Pandas trying to create columns from existing column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe based on airports that has a type column with values:
small_airport,
medium_airport,
large_airport

I need to extract these values in to 3 different columns and I'm a bit stuck. I have tried various permutations of:

```
data['small_airport'] = data[['type'] == 'small_airport']
```

But I can't get anything to work. I have seen several similar posts on here but have not really understood the answers fully enough to implement the suggestions so sorry if I am duplicating questions.

Any advice would be much appreciated!
Edit:
A sample of the data is:

```
id, type, name
652, small_airport, Total Rf
345, heliport, Aero B
654, large_airport, Lowell field
```

It is a university project and the brief states:
**The ‘type’ column contains information of the type of airport. Extract this out into a new column, one for each category of airport**

I hope that helps!

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data and a required output ? It would help understand what you want.

Comment: Edited with data samples

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `data.groupby('type')` and then do aggregations (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)) (which will be most useful for most purposes), or use `data.pivot(index=..., columns='type', values=...)` (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)) (which is a more exact answer to your question).

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.crosstab`:

```
out = pd.concat([df, pd.crosstab(df.index, df['type'])], axis=1)
print(out)

# Output
  name            type  large_airport  medium_airport  small_airport
0    A   small_airport              0               0              1
1    B   small_airport              0               0              1
2    C   large_airport              1               0              0
3    D  medium_airport              0               1              0
```

Note: if you prefer boolean values, use `pd.crosstab(...).astype(bool)`.

Setup:

```
data = {
    'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'type': ['small_airport', 'small_airport', 'large_airport', 'medium_airport']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```